# problems with the first time using pdflatex

Tags: texlive, installing, linux

I used this method to install TeX Live: [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu/95373#95373)

It is recommended in that post to edit `/etc/environment`. But another post recommends editing `~/.bashrc`. The latter was what I did and add these lines:

```
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
```

But when I want to use `pdflatex` Fedora22 doesn't find it... What can i do?

Comment: do you use bash as your command shell? Does the file /usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex exist with executable permissions?

Comment: Did you source your `~/.bashrc` file? That is, did you log out/log in, restart, or type `source ~/.bashrc` at the command line? (any of those options should work)

Comment: What does `which pdflatex` returns?

Comment: /usr/bin/which: no tex in (/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/home/zorn/.local/bin:/home/zorn/bin)

Comment: What's the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: You need `export PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH"`.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Presumably `/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/s‌​bin:/home/zorn/.local/bin:/home/zorn/bin`?

Comment: ➜  ~  echo $PATH
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/home/zorn/.local/bin:/home/zorn/bin